# art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, libc, anr

Our mobile app is published in the Google play store. The Crashes and ANR report is generated in Firebase Crashlytics. There is an ANR shown as below.

0
libc.so
(syscall+28)

1
libart.so
(art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+140)

2
libart.so
(art::ThreadList::WaitForOtherNonDaemonThreadsToExit(bool)+336)

3
libart.so
(art::JII::DestroyJavaVM(_JavaVM*)+32)

4
libandroid_runtime.so
(android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vectorandroid::String8 const&, bool)+1032)

5
app_process64
(main+1368)

6
libc.so
(__libc_init+96)

What does this ANR mean?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: We're also seeing this crash. It only seems to happen on Pixel devices running Android 13. We've tried to disable hardware acceleration on all AdView but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I think it has something to do with keep waking up screen or screen on all the time. I have the same error report, but I could not find a solution yet.

Comment: samsung SC-52D, samsung c2s, samsung r0q, samsung SC-52C too. Yes, I use getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: ANR means Application Not Responding… usually when main thread/ui thread is frozen over 5s…

Answer (score 5):

I believe it has a connection with some routine added in mobile app which is preventing screen from sleep. For example:
If your mobile app used the following code to prevent the screen from sleep
"getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);"
This issue is not device specific, I also experience this on Samsung Galaxy active tab with Android 11 running on it.
You should give it a try by removing any screen prevention code.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are right. I am working in one app that makes a device to wake up from asleep every time there is a notification. I am not using the flag that you mentioned, I am using PowerManager.WakeLock. App works as I expected but the problem is that every now and then app crashes and get this crash report in firebase crashletic. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How did you find the connection between the error and that flag?

Comment: It's a guess, that whenever I uses FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON it keeps happening, need to dig into this