# firebase ANR interpretation

Tags: android, firebase

I'm investigating some ANR that are frequently impatting user experience of our app. On the firebase consolo, under the logs tab, I can see the following info:

```
1 screen_view
Parameters
firebase_screen_class: IdGatewayActivityNew

2
07:08:54.217 pm
screen_view
Parameters
firebase_screen_class: OnboardingActivity

3
07:08:54.200 pm
session_start
```

Under the stack trace tab I see:

```
  #00 pc 0x881b0 libc.so (syscall + 32) (BuildId: 69c79353981108b70293a7a6056f9a50)
  #01 pc 0x3a9984 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 140) (BuildId: 289d75599f6112d5757113220599e90b)
  #02 pc 0x726740 libart.so (art::ThreadList::WaitForOtherNonDaemonThreadsToExit(bool) + 336) (BuildId: 289d75599f6112d5757113220599e90b)
  #03 pc 0x34dac0 libart.so (art::JII::DestroyJavaVM(_JavaVM*) + 32) (BuildId: 289d75599f6112d5757113220599e90b)
  #04 pc 0xbf1e8 libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool) + 1016) (BuildId: dbcfd4c080a40e93547a00f7932647f9)
  #05 pc 0x2684 app_process64 (main + 1580) (BuildId: 6a17c4f390bb08d15280ace738df870c)
  #06 pc 0x8436c libc.so (__libc_init + 100) (BuildId: 69c79353981108b70293a7a6056f9a50)
```

This stack trace is pretty unreadable to me but thread is marked as "Triggered ANR" and "Root blocking". Now I'm wondering if the information provided in logs tab mean that the ANR has been triggered when the user was in the IdGatewayActivityNew view. Is that correct?

Comment: I face the same problem. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331666/artconditionvariablewaitholdinglocksartthread) seems to relate that to screen save prevention. Could it be your case ?